# segmentation fault in my binary search tree code while file handling

Tags: c, io, binary-search-tree

The code is error free but does not run. I have applied various print statements near the file handling. The problem appears to be there. Can someone see if they find the problem?

My input file has data in the format:

```
Insert "tab>" "name" "tab""IDNo" "tab" "Department""newline"  
Delete "tab""IDNO""newline"  
Find"tab"IDNO"newline"
```

Code:

```
/*bst.h*/

typedef struct{
    unsigned int id;
    char name[20];
    char dep[10];
    }studRec;

struct bst;
typedef struct bst binTree;
typedef struct binTree *BST;
struct binTree{
    studRec sRec;
    BST left;
    BST right;
    };

/* bstMain.c*/

#include "bstOps.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    int s;
    int key,i;
    FILE *f;
    char a[4][20];
    f=fopen("input.txt","r");
    if(f==NULL)
     printf("error");
    else
            printf("no error");
    char ch=getc(f);

    studRec rec;
    BST bt=createEmptyBST();



    do{
            for(i=0;ch!='\n';i++)
                    fscanf(f,"%s",a[i]);

            if(a[0]=="Insert")
                    s=1;
            else if(a[0]=="Delete")
                    {s=2;
                     key=atoi(a[1]);}

            else if(a[0]=="Find"){
                    s=3;
                    key=atoi(a[1]);}
            printf("To print the list, press 4\n To exit,press 5.\n");
            scanf("%d",&s);



    switch(s){
            case 1:

            strcpy(rec.name,a[1]);
            rec.id=atoi(a[2]);
            strcpy(rec.dep,a[3]);
            bt=insertInBST(bt,rec);
            break;

            case 2:

            bt=deleteFromBST(bt,key);
            break;

            case 3:
            rec=findInBST(bt,key);

            case 4:

            inorderTraversal(bt);
            break;

            case 5:

            printf("\nTerminating!!!\n");
            break;

            default:
            printf("\nInvalid Option!! \n");
            break;}
            ch=getc(f);

            }while(ch!=EOF||s==5);
            fclose(f);

}

/*bstOps.c*/

#include "bstOps.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

BST createEmptyBST(){
    BST root;
    root=(BST)malloc(sizeof(BST));
//      root->sRec=(studRec *)malloc(sizeof(studRec));
    root->sRec.id=0;
    strcpy(root->sRec.name,"/");
    strcpy(root->sRec.dep,"/");
    root->left=NULL;
    root->right=NULL;
    //root=NULL;
    return root;
    }

BST insertInBST(BST bt,studRec rec){

    BST bt1=createEmptyBST();
    bt1=bt;

    while(1){
    /*      if(bt==NULL){
                    bt->sRec=rec;
                    bt->left=NULL;
                    bt->right=NULL;
                    break;}
*/
            if(bt->sRec.id==rec.id)
            {
            return bt;
            break;
            }
            else if(rec.id<bt->sRec.id){
                    if(bt->left==NULL){
                    bt->left=createEmptyBST();
                    bt=bt->left;
                    bt->sRec=rec;
                    break;
                    }
                    else
                            bt=bt->left;
                    }
            else{
                    if(bt->right==NULL){
                    bt->right=createEmptyBST();
                    bt=bt->right;
                    bt->sRec=rec;
                    break;
                    }
                    else
                            bt=bt->right;
            }

    }
    printf("inserted\n");
    return bt1;
    }


void inorderTraversal(BST bt){
    if(bt!=NULL){
            inorderTraversal(bt->left);
            if(bt->sRec.id!=0)
            printf("\t Id:%d\n Name:%s\n Deparment:%s\n",bt->sRec.id,bt->sRec.name,bt->sRec.dep);
            inorderTraversal(bt->right);
            }
    }

studRec findInBST(BST bt,int id){
    BST temp=createEmptyBST();
    if(bt==NULL||bt->sRec.id==0)
            return temp->sRec;
    if(id>bt->sRec.id)
            return findInBST(bt->right,id);
    else if(id<bt->sRec.id)
            return findInBST(bt->left,id);
    else
            return bt->sRec;



}

BST deleteFromBST(BST bt,int id){
    BST q;
    if(bt==NULL||bt->sRec.id==0){
            printf("\nElement not found\n");
            }


    else if(id>bt->sRec.id)
            bt->right=deleteFromBST(bt->right,id);
    else{
            if(bt->right && bt->left){
                    q=FindMin(bt->right);
                    bt->sRec=q->sRec;
                    bt->right=deleteFromBST(bt->right,q->sRec.id);
                    }
            else{
                    q=bt;
                    if(bt->left==NULL)
                            bt=bt->right;
                    else if(bt->right==NULL)
                            bt=bt->left;
                    free(q);
                    }
            }
            return bt;
    }

    BST FindMin(BST bt){
    if(bt==NULL||bt->sRec.id==0){
            return NULL;
            }
    if(bt->left)
            return FindMin(bt->left);
    else
            return bt;
    }
 int getHeight(BST bt){
    int h,lh,rh;
    h=lh=rh-0;
    if(bt->left!=NULL)
            lh=(1+getHeight(bt->left));
    else if(bt->right!=NULL)
            rh=(1+getHeight(bt->right));
    h=lh>rh?lh:rh;
    return(h);
    }
```

Comment: You need to review your code first. It contains some error:
 **1.** use `strcmp` for string comparison (not `==` operator)
 **2.** in `getHeight()`, I think it is `h=lh=rh=0` not `h=lh=rh-0`
 **3.** `FindMin` returns a pointer. Check its return against `NULL` before using it.
 **4.** In main function, your `for` will never stop. You are checking against `ch` which not changing.
 **5.** Check the remark of mani

Comment: 1) `}while(ch != EOF && s != 5);` . 2) `if(f==NULL)
     { fprintf(stderr, "error"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}` 3) `for(i=0;ch!='\n';i++)` is loop invariant.

Answer (score 0):

The crash was caused by the invariant loop:

```
for(i=0;ch!='\n';i++)
    fscanf(f,"%s",a[i]);
```

The stop condition will never be TRUE, you end up by overwriting the array `a` which will cause a segmentation fault.

Here a fix proposal. You need to update it according to your needs

```
int getHeight(BST bt) {
    int h, lh, rh;
    h = lh = rh = 0;
    if (bt->left != NULL )
        lh = (1 + getHeight(bt->left));
    else if (bt->right != NULL )
        rh = (1 + getHeight(bt->right));
    h = lh > rh ? lh : rh;
    return (h);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int s;
    int key = 0, i;
    FILE *f;
    char line[200];
    char options[5][200];
    f = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if (f == NULL ) {
        printf("error");
        return -1;
    }

    printf("no error");

    char ch = fgetc(f);
    studRec rec;
    BST bt = createEmptyBST();

    do {

        for (i = 0; ch != '\n' && ch != EOF; i++) {
            line[i] = ch;
            ch = fgetc(f);
        }

        if (EOF == ch) {
            printf("To print the list, press 4\n To exit,press 5.\n");
            scanf("%d", &s);
        }

        if (!strncmp(line, "Insert", strlen("Insert"))) {
            s = 1;
            // TODO parse the line string to get your options
            sprintf(line, "Insert %s %s %s", options[0], options[1], options[2]);
        } else if (!strncmp(line, "Delete", strlen("Delete"))) {
            s = 2;
            key = atoi(line + strlen("Delete") + 1);
        } else if (!strncmp(line, "Find", strlen("Find"))) {
            s = 3;
            key = atoi(line + strlen("Find") + 1);
        }

        switch (s) {
        case 1:

            strcpy(rec.name, options[0]);
            rec.id = atoi(options[1]);
            strcpy(rec.dep, options[2]);
            bt = insertInBST(bt, rec);
            break;

        case 2:
            bt = deleteFromBST(bt, key);
            break;

        case 3:
            rec = findInBST(bt, key);
            break;

        case 4:

            inorderTraversal(bt);
            break;

        case 5:

            printf("\nTerminating!!!\n");
            ch = EOF; // to  break the do {} while() loop
            break;

        default:
            printf("\nInvalid Option!! \n");
            break;
        }

    } while (ch != EOF || s == 5);
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Still need to fix `}while(ch != EOF && s != 5)` .